# Querying Active Directory with "SQL"?

Tags: .net, active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I just wonder if anyone knows or made a wrapper around Active Directory to be able to easily query it in .net? Kind of like "LINQ-to-ActiveDirectory" or some SQL Dialect, i.e. to be able to do "SELECT DISTINCT(DEPARTMENT) FROM /Users/SomeOU/AnotherOU" or "SELECT user FROM domain" or whatever.

As far as I know, it is possible to query WMI and IIS in a "SQLesque" way, i just wonder if something similar is possible for Active Directory as well, without having to learn yet another Query Language (LDAP)?

Comment: +1 I found this post instead! ;) Hehehe...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> LINQ to Active Directory implements a
>   custom LINQ query provider that allows
>   querying objects in Active Directory.
>   Internally, queries are translated
>   into LDAP filters which are sent to
>   the server using the
>   System.DirectoryServices .NET
>   Framework library.

http://www.codeplex.com/LINQtoAD

Sample (from the site):

```
// NOTE: Entity type definition "User" omitted in sample - see samples in release.

var users = new DirectorySource<User>(ROOT, SearchScope.Subtree);
users.Log = Console.Out;

var res = from usr in users
          where usr.FirstName.StartsWith("B") && usr.Office == "2525"
          select new { Name = usr.FirstName + " " + usr.LastName, usr.Office, usr.LogonCount };

foreach (var u in res)
{
    Console.WriteLine(u);
    u.Office = "5252";
    u.SetPassword(pwd);
}

users.Update();
```

Comment: Now I feel stupid, could not find that in Google earlier :-) Thanks!

Comment: That happens to everyone once in i while. Next time someone needs this, they will find this stackoverflow-post instead.